# Search through NSArray for string

Tags: search, nsstring, nsarray

I would like to search through my NSArray for a certain string.

Example:

NSArray has the objects: "dog", "cat", "fat dog", "thing", "another thing", "heck here's another thing"

I want to search for the word "another" and put the results into one array, and have the other, non results, into another array that can be filtered further.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Not tested so might have a syntax error, but you'll get the idea.

```
NSArray* inputArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dog", @"cat", @"fat dog", @"thing", @"another thing", @"heck here's another thing", nil];

NSMutableArray* containsAnother = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* doesntContainAnother = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString* item in inputArray)
{
  if ([item rangeOfString:@"another"].location != NSNotFound)
    [containsAnother addObject:item];
  else
    [doesntContainAnother addObject:item];
}
```

Comment: This code works great but how could I find out the index in the array of the found string?

Comment: Sovled it myself:                                                        for (NSString* item in inputArray)
{                                                                    index++;
  if ([item rangeOfString:@"another"].location != NSNotFound) {
    [containsAnother addObject:item];                                 saveIndex = index - 1;                                               }
  else
    [doesntContainAnother addObject:item];
}

Answer (score 47):

If the strings inside the array are known to be distinct, you can use sets. NSSet is faster then NSArray on large inputs:

```
NSArray * inputArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"one again", nil];

NSMutableSet * matches = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:inputArray];
[matches filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'one'"]];

NSMutableSet * notmatches = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:inputArray];
[notmatches  minusSet:matches];
```

Answer (score 1):

It would not work because as per document "indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:" returns the index of the first object that has the same memory address as the object you are passing in.

you need to traverse through your array and compare.