# Checking if a word is in database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm making this word game and when you submit a word I want that word to be checked if I have it in my 'database' I've setup a couple of words for example

```
word1: banana
word2: apple
word3: pineapple
word4: lemon
```

now I can do this by the code:

```
If (submitword isequalto banana){
//submitword
}
else if (submitword isequalto apple){
//submitword
}

else{
//give warning
}
```

the problem is that I got thousands of words and the 'submitword' action is hundreds of lines long so that would make my code way to long.

anyone knows an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what kind of 'database' you are using. E.g. if you are using an external API (as many current word app do) it can decide for you if it is correct or not. Then you could use MySQL or any other type of SQL server and make some intelligent questions using SQL.

I get the idea that you need to write down what you want to do first, then investigate the best way of doing it, and then start implementing code. Design first principle!

Comment: no I didn't know the right word for database sorry about that, at the moment the words are in my code

Comment: ok... thats sounds kind of expensive. At least your words *should* be in a extenal file such as a plist. Otherwise if you have them in an NSArray you can search trhough that array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853801/search-through-nsarray-for-string

Comment: Oke right now I have them in a random word generator which is based in the view did load section so I didn't think it would work like this ill check out your link thanks

Comment: Is there not away to say 'or' because I use '==' equal to and '!=' not equal to. Is there a way to say if 'inputword' == 'submitword1' 'or' 'submitword2'

Comment: Well, what you want to know is wether the submitword exists in your 'database', right? If so, you do not need a large if-case, you just need to search the array to see if the word exists in the array or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which checks if the word is valid, and subsequently submit if ok.
For this you can perhaps store your words in some list, this reduces the function to a single list lookup

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you extract the list of words from the DB before the games start into a container object (Say `NSDictionary`) and check if the word exists against that list