# Searching an array for a string

Tags: ios

What I am trying to achieve is to search an array for a string, here is the code for searching the array

```
    if ([EssentialsArray containsObject:imageFilePath]) {

        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"NO");
        NSLog(@"%@", ImageFilePath);
        NSLog(@"%@", EssentialsArray);
    }
```

The NSLogs return this for the imageFilePath:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/5051DC84-CAC8-4C1D-841D-5539A1E28CB1/Documents/12242012_11025125_image.jpg
```

And this for the EssentialsArray:

```
(
        {
        EssentialImage = "/var/mobile/Applications/5051DC84-CAC8-4C1D-841D-5539A1E28CB1/Documents/12242012_11025125_image.jpg";
    }
)
```

And then obviously they return a "NO" value because the array couldn't find the string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't specify your array type, but isn't this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853801/search-through-nsarray-for-string

Comment: @cppl Completely forgot too specify the array type, and thanks thats the same as what I am asking and solves my question. Dont know why it didn't come up in my searches. Cheers

Comment: @cppl, It is not duplicate of that. This looks like a different question. Here the problem is the objects are dictionaries and he is trying to check for strings.

Comment: @ACB ok... well I guess Duck got some value out of my comment.

Comment: Yeah I only quickly went over the post, didn't read it thoroughly. Unfortunately cppl was right and that post wasn't the same.
I still appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the invocation of `[EssentialsArray containsObject:imageFilePath]` clearly assumes that `EssentialsArray` is an array of strings, whereas it's not. It's an array of dictionary entries with one key, `EssentialImage`.

There are at least two solutions. The first is to make an array of strings for those dictionary entries whose key is `EssentialImage`:

```
NSArray *essentialImages = [essentialsArray valueForKey:@"EssentialImage"];

if ([essentialImages containsObject:imagePath])
    NSLog(@"YES");
else
    NSLog(@"NO");
```

Depending upon the size of your `essentialsArray` (please note, convention dictates that variables always start with a lower case letter), this seems a little wasteful to create an array just so you can do `containsObject`, but it works.

Second, and better in my opinion is to use fast enumeration to go through your array of dictionary entries, looking for a match. To do this, define a method:

```
- (BOOL)arrayOfDictionaries:(NSArray *)array
       hasDictionaryWithKey:(id)key
             andStringValue:(NSString *)value
{
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
        if ([dictionary[key] isEqualToString:value]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

You can now check to see if your array of dictionaries has a key called `@"EssentialImage"` with a string value equal to the string contained by `imagePath`

```
if ([self arrayOfDictionaries:essentialsArray
         hasDictionaryWithKey:@"EssentialImage" 
               andStringValue:imagePath])
    NSLog(@"YES");
else
    NSLog(@"NO");
```

---

Update:

You can also use [predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"EssentialImage contains %@", imagePath];

BOOL found = [predicate evaluateWithObject:array];
```

Comment: Also thanks for putting in the time to explain how it all works.