# Searching NSMutableArray v.s. Sqlite search query

Tags: ios, sqlite, search

I have an app with a relatively large **SQLite** database, containing around `15,000` rows. At the start of the app, I run a `SELECT * FROM TABLE` query and populate a `NSMutableArray *data` containing elements of a class `ProverbRow`. Each `ProverbRow` object corresponds to one row of data from the database and contains `NSString`s and `NSInteger`s corresponding to each cell of the database. So, effectively the `NSMutableArray *data` object is a copy of the **SQLite** database.

Now, to the question...

I want to add a **search** functionality in the app like this example :

When the user types in "abc" and taps search, I want to get all the elements of `data` where the `NSString *proverb` inside the `ProverbRow` object contains the string "abc" as the substring. So, the strings like "abcde", "qqqabcqqq", etc. should be obtained.

Currently, to accomplish this, I am firing a query like this : `SELECT * FROM PROVERB WHERE PRONUNCIATION LIKE abc`. The objects which I get back from the query are stored in another `NSArray` for further use.

Now, if there are only a small number of objects getting returned, then this query completes fast enough, but with larger number of rows, it takes a lot of time.

I was wondering whether there is a quicker way to accomplish this apart from firing the query. Is it possible to use the already populated `data` object and run it through a loop and equating the substring or something like that? **My main concern is to reduce the time search takes.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15 k is tiny. Just do a linear scan of the in-memory objects.

The following test finds the `xyz` at the end of the alphabet 15000 times. Repeating this process 100 times took 4.7 s on my iPhone 5. That's 47 ms for a full scan that returns every element.

```
NSMutableArray * data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15000];
for (int i = 0; i < 15000; ++i)
    [data addObject:@[@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", @123]];

NSLog(@"Starting test");
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    NSIndexSet * s = [data indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString * s = obj[0];
        return [s rangeOfString:@"xyz"].location != NSNotFound;
    }];
    count += s.count;
}
NSLog(@"Finished test: %d", count); // Outputs 1500000
```

Let me reiterate: 15 k is tiny.

Comment: Would a linear scan of the populated NSMutableArray like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853801/search-through-nsarray-for-string) be faster than the search query?

Comment: I've amended my answer with a quick analysis. To answer your question directly: yes, it will be faster because you avoid enormous amounts of overhead going from a dynamically typed disk storage format through SQLite's VM and finally out through its API. SQLite would have a significant advantage if it could use indexes, but it can't do so with `LIKE '%abc%'`. As such, it has no advantage, and doesn't stand a chance against raw native code.

Comment: Yep, I implemented this code, and wow it has a huge speed improvement! Thanks